# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

I'm trying to learn myself some PHP, finally.

I've decided that I would like to build my own website, with a CMS instead of just downloading something premade.
I found this great guide (http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/#step1) to get me started.

So far so good, I've followed the guide, changing a few things so that it would suit my needs and I am now testing my website using XAMPP.

I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'jobs' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Grogglenscrib\index.php on line 8

The code for the index.php file is as follows. Feel free to ask for some more code if that is needed.

```
    <?php

require( "config.php" );
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

    switch ( $action ) {
        case 'jobs'
            jobs():
            break;
        case 'viewJob'
            viewJob():
            break;
        default:
            homepage():
    }

    function jobs() {
        $results = array();
        $data = Job::getList();
        $results['jobs'] = $data['results'];
        $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
        $results['pageTitle'] = "Job Archive | News"
        require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/archive.php" );
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `:` after `case`.

Corrected Code:

```
<?php
require( "config.php" );
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

    switch ( $action ) {
        case 'jobs'://Add : here
            jobs():
            break;
        case 'viewJob'://Add : here
            viewJob(); // Replace `:` by `;` here
            break;
        default:
            homepage(); // Replace `:` by `;` here
    }

    function jobs() {
        $results = array();
        $data = Job::getList();
        $results['jobs'] = $data['results'];
        $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
        $results['pageTitle'] = "Job Archive | News";
        require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/archive.php" );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
switch ( $action ) {
    case 'jobs':
        jobs();
        break;
    case 'viewJob':
        viewJob();
        break;
    default:
        homepage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs():
```

needs to be ; for all functions in the switch statement

except in the `case 'jobs':`